# Display proper result of integers

Tags: c++, int, cout

I have a code that shows the result in this form: example

```
  Amount:          10
  Total Amount:    200
  Tax:             30
  Net Balance:     2000
```

and my desire to show the result such as math type begin from right hand side and with 2 zero(00) after a decimal point. Example

```
  Amount:           10.00
  Total Amount:    200.00
  Tax:              30.00
  Net Balance:    2000.00
```

I am using double int for it, but really i don't know how to set the resulted amount begin from right side with an sequence and with a point and zeros.

Comment: Try [formatting](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html) your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout << "Tax:         " << std::setw(8) << std::fixed << float(30) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Net balance: "<< std::setw(8) << std::fixed << float(2000) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine a few settings from `<iomanip>`:

```
std::cout << std::fixed;   // formatting floating-point numbers
std::cout << std::setprecision(2); // number of floating-point digits
std::cout << std::setw(10);  // width of the whole output string
std::cout << std::right;  // padding to the right
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
double v = 123.45;

printf("%5.2f",v);
```

Specify the width(5 in my case) and the precision(2) required.

Edits: The number of fields is specified as the width and number of digits in the precision part should be mentioned after `.` in the `printf()` . Take a look at the below outputs.

```
   double v = 123456.45;
   printf("%3.2f\n",v);
   printf("%10.2f\n",v);
   printf("%11.2f\n",v);
   printf("%12.2f\n",v);
```

Output:

```
123456.45
 123456.45
  123456.45
   123456.45
```

Comment: Will this take care of the alignment?

Comment: @SouravGhosh You can specify the width accrodingly to align the output

Comment: @ZainabNabeel Now with this in the output 5 fields are outputted and the value is filed in it with precision set to 2 decimal points. Accordingly you can align your output